# How to add a custom @Cacheable cache while keeping cache autoconfiguration?

Tags: java, spring, caching

The following will tell `spring` to automatically generate a simple `ConcurrentHashMap` with the cachename "simpleCache".

```
@Cachable("simpleCache")
public String simpleCache(String val) {
     //...
}

@Cache("selfexpire")
public String selfexpireLookup(String val) {

}
```

Question: what if I want to add only one cache that has a defined self-expire time, but want to rely on springs autoconfigured hashmaps for all other `@Cacheable` I use?

The following creates the cache:

```
@Bean
public CaffeineCache selfexpireCache() {
    return new CaffeineCache("selfexpire",
            Caffeine.newBuilder()
                    .maximumSize(100)
                    .expireAfterAccess(1, TimeUnit.HOURS)
                    .build());
}
```

BUT: whan I now start my application, all other once autoconfigured caches fail with:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find cache named 'simpleCache' for Builder`... Only the caffeing cache explicit configured works.

So, how can I keep autoconfigured caches while explicit adding a custom one?

Of course I could add those simple caches manually, but I'd prefer spring to autoconfigure them:

```
@Bean
public ConcurrentMapCache simpleCache() {
    return new ConcurrentMapCache("simpleCache");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use different types of caches by specifying an explicit `org.springframework.cache.CacheManager` that is to be used:

```
@Cachable(value = "simpleCache", cacheManager="simpleCacheManager")
public String getValueFromSimpleCache(String val) {
  //...
}
```

Not sure what spring's default `CacheManager`'s bean name is. Maybe you need to declare it explicitly:

```
@Bean
public CacheMananger simpleCacheManager() {
  return new ConcurrentMapCacheManager();
}
```

Comment: You got me wrong: the selfexpireCache works as expected and configured with caffeine. Just the normally autoconfigured `ConcurrentHashMap` cache `somecache` is not initialized anymore. I'd like to tell spring to still init those caches that have not explicit defined a caffeine cache.

Comment: @membersound are you still looking for another answer? What aspect of this answer doesn’t work or is too complicated?